# Limit number of button click And insert index to id/name of element

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm trying to upload image and if I were need to add more images, I just simply need to click the button. Now,  I have done the button and it works but the problem now is since new fields are created for uploading image, the name and id of the elements are similar. So, the javascript won't work. I think I need to insert index into the element but I can't figure it out how. Thanks!

```js
function createGambar() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'input-group');
  newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='col-sm-6'><span>Lampiran 1</span><div class='input-group'><input type='text' class='form-control bg-light' id='label_file' disabled placeholder='Gambar'><input type='file' name='lampiran1' id='file1' hidden onchange='setFileName();'><div class='input-group-append'><div class='btn btn-primary px-4' id='browse_button'onclick='document.getElementById(\"file1\").click();'><i class='fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass'></i></div></div></div><center class='mt-2'><img id='thumb' src='' class='preview' /></center></div><div class='col-sm-6'><span>Kapsyen Gambar 1</span><div class='input-group mb-3'> <textarea class='form-control' style='resize:none' name='kapsyen' id='kapsyen' cols='20' rows='3'placeholder='e.g YM Pengarah Memberi Cenderahati Kepada Tetamu Jemputan' required></textarea></div></div>";
  document.getElementById("newGambar").appendChild(newDiv);
}

function setFileName() {
  var fileName = document.getElementById("file1");
  document.getElementById("label_file").value = fileName.files[0].name;
  preview1();
}

function preview1() {
  thumb.src = "";
  if (event.target.files[0]['type'].split('/')[0] === 'image') {
    thumb.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="newGambar"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <button type="button" id="buttonAdd" class="btn btn-success mt-1 w-100" onclick="createGambar(); "><i class="fa-solid fa-add"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tambah Perkembangan</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (offtopic) `<center>` element is deprecated. Use CSS instead. Also learn how to use Template Literals. It will help you greatly to create templates.

Comment: Don't *just* rely on global `thumb`. Define it like `const thumb = document.querySelector("#thumb")` - also, you're appending always elements with ID. But IDs are supposed to be **unique**. Rethink your logic in such way that you don't need IDs.